# How to play widevine drm video in android

Tags: android

I have a requirement, where I need to play widevine DRM content using Android media player. I have also heard about something called ExoPlayer which has an inbuilt support for widevine DRM contents.

For a start, I want to know what are the prerequisites needed to start playing such content using either of the above media players.

Comment: `widevine drm content` any description of what is it? Also, why don't you just try to play it using `ExoPlayer` as you said?

Comment: But i want to know how to play using default android Media Player

Comment: what about the first part of my comment?

Comment: Widevine DRM is a Combination of a Few Leading Technologies. MPEG-DASH. This is an open-source adaptive bitrate for streaming video across the internet. Like it's ABR predecessors, DASH leverages standard protocols like HTTP using existing web infrastructure to deliver video to every device

Comment: I am able to play Widevine DRM content with the use of ExoPlayer. Can anyone tell me wether Widevine DRM contents can be played locally instead of streaming

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, yes to the original question as I think you already know now - ExoPlayer will play Widevine protected content so long as the device supports widevine, and has the correct widevine level for the content.

Widevine has different levels of protection depending on how 'deeply' the security is integrated into the device and some content owners only allow high value and high resolution content when the highest level of integration is available.

For the question in your last comment, which I think maybe brings this up in searches still, the answer is also yes - you can play local content which is encrypted and using widevine DRM. If the device is online it will request the key as usual. Even if the device is offline, if the key is persistent and you have requested it before you go offline you can play the content.